# Aptana Studio 3 - No More Progress Dialog?

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I can't imagine that this would be anything but a simple option somewhere, but I can't for the life of me figure out why Aptana's progress dialog no longer pops up. Instead, when something is in progress (i.e. a file upload, a search, etc), it shows a little indicator on the statusbar, like this:

http://screencast.com/t/fHduxs98exwI

I can of course explicitly dock progress window like any other:

http://screencast.com/t/R5z6THXyle

But then it just sits there uselessly taking up screen real estate when nothing is going on. It used to bring up a nice dialog when a process started, and hide when the process finished. I've Googled and Googled but can't find this option, nor can I find anything in the help docs or options. Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am not shure if i understand your wish exactly but maybe this helps:

in preferences -> General -> UN-Check the option 
"always run in background" (in a windows system it is in Window -> preferences)

When now i upload lots of files, i get a popup window with the progress bar. 
i can send this specific window in to background (so next time it will again open
or 
again also activate the option "always run in background" in that dialog.
then it is as before ..

Greetigns from munich 
joerg

Comment: That's it!! Exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks you so much - ugh, what an unclearly-named option; I've no idea how that became spontaneously checked...

Comment: `I've no idea how that became spontaneously checked` -> that is now easy to be ansewered: normal there is a checkbox on every popup prgress window: always run in background ... once checked popup will never come ...

Comment: Ah yes - that would make sense :)

Answer (score 1):

I want to add a little tip. After uncheck the `Always run in background option`, I had to go to `Window > Show View > Others`, and search for `Progress`.